# Conjugate Elements in Cycle Notation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let σ= (1438)(265) and let τ= (163)(752).  So I have a question that is saying that you can write $τστ^{-1}$ as a cycle decomposition without doing any work.  I did the work and got it to equal (1864)(273) but how is it possible to write this down quickly without showing any work?  Is their a theorem?

Comment: There is a theorem and you are more likely to guess what it is if you fix the computation you made. I am pretty sure the question asks about $\tau^{-1}\sigma\tau$, not $\tau\sigma^{-1}\tau$. Then do several examples.

Comment: @EthanBolker that's what I meant, just a typo but I still don't know the theorem

Comment: The statement is that conjugate permutations have the same cycle type. Maybe try to prove that on your own.

Comment: If that's what you did (as well as what you meant) then you did the multiplication wrong. @Arthur has provided a correct answer. (Maybe he should have waited so you'd have more time to find it yourself.)

Comment: @EthanBolker there was a mistake in the way I typed the question,  σ= (1438)(265) not  σ= (1438).  My bad!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conjugating $\sigma$ by $\tau$ corresponds to renaming the entries in $\sigma$ via $\tau$.

So, $\sigma = (1438)$. Then $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}$ is simply
$$
(\tau(1)\tau(4)\tau(3)\tau(8))
$$
assuming you are applying permutations in order from right to left.

This is easy to check. For instance, $\tau(1)$ is sent to $1$ by $\tau^{-1}$, then to $4$ by $\sigma$, and then to $\tau(4)$ by $\tau$.

Comment: So I did make a mistake with the typing of the question it's actually (1438)(265).  I'm assuming this does not affect your explanation that much as would the three cycle be ((2)(6)(5)).  Now I did the work for it and I got the identity for the right and (163)(275) for the left so that means it equals (163)(275).  So does this mean all it's doing is it swapping the two elements of ?  However I am multiplying and still getting the above answer for handwriting it so I am not sure if what I am doing that you explained is wrong or if my handwritten work for $τστ^{-1}$  is just simply wrong

Comment: @user710744 What do you men "the identity for the right and (163)(275) for the left"? What "right" and "left"?

Comment: I am most likely not speaking in great math terms and I am sorry for that.  (1438)(265) is the "left" per say and (163)(275) is the "right".  I did the method that you explained above, ((1)(4)(3)(8))((2)(6)(5)) (this is what I am considering to be the left hand side) and I did the same to ((1)(6)(3))((2)(7)(5)) to the right hand side so I set it up like this ((1)(4)(3)(8))((2)(6)(5))*((1)(6)(3))((2)(7)(5)).  Simplyfing I got (163)(275) for the "left" and the  identity for the"right" hence (163)(275)*e=(163)(275)

Comment: Is what I got from your explanation not correct @Arthur

Comment: That's not what I'm saying at all. I'm saying that $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}$ is equal to $$(\tau(1)\tau(4)\tau(3)\tau(8))(\tau(2)\tau(6)\tau(5))$$That's it.

Comment: Okay I guess my question is what does that mean cause clearly I do not understand what you mean by that.  For example starting from all the way to the right 5 maps to 2 since =(163)(752) then we say 2 maps to 7 based on the next  and we keep doing this until we reach that last  and see 5 maps to 2.  Or are staying in the parentheses and saying 5 maps to 5.  I am just trying to understand the concept.

Comment: We have $\tau(2)=7,\tau(6)=3$ and $\tau(5)=2$. So when I write $(\tau(2)\tau(6)\tau(5))$, that's the same as $(732)$. That's the three-cycle of $\sigma$ conjugated. Then we do the same for the four-cycle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99442/discussion-between-user710744-and-arthur).

Comment: @user71744 I won't do that. I don't get notified in chat, so it's somewhere where I will have to actively check for responses, compared to a comment thread where I will automatically see whenever there is a response. I know the site tends to suggest moving to chat when a discussion goes on long enough, but I strongly prefer not to go in there.

Comment: I was just saying thank you cause I didn't want to extend the comments.  I totally get what you were saying now.  Sorry you had to explain it multiple times, thanks again!

Comment: @user710744 No worries. If I was bothered by having to explain multiple times, I wouldn't have responded. I also likely wouldn't have been as much as I am on this site.